# Bug jQuery: trigger draggable 'TypeError: ui is undefined'

Tags: jquery

I can't understand why I have this error: **TypeError: ui is undefined**

Yet the code is very simple! **demo code:** http://jsfiddle.net/9sNEK/19/

The Final Goal is when I drag the green div it triggers the dragging of the red div

**JS**

```
$('.div_green')
.draggable()
.bind('drag',function(event,ui){

    $('.div_red').trigger('drag');

    $('.log').html("drag green - left:" + ui.position.left);

});

$('.div_red')
    .draggable()
    .bind('drag', function(event,ui){

        $('.log2').html("drag_to_simulate - left:"+ ui.position.left);

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="div_green"></div>

<div class="pdrag" id="pdrag1">
    <div class="div_red"></div>
</div>

<div class="pdrag" id="pdrag2">
    <div class="div_red"></div>
</div>

<div class="log" style="width:200px;height:20px;"></div>
<div class="log2" style="width:200px;height:20px;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div_green, .pdrag, .div_red{
  position:absolute;
}
.div_green{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  top:170px;
  left:300px;
  background-color: green;
}
.pdrag{
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  top:50px;
  left:90px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
#pdrag2{
  top:230px;
  width:150px;
}
.div_red{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  top:40px;
  left:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
#pdrag2 .div_red{
    left:75px
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting `TypeError: ui is undefined` because you trigger the drag event of .div_red in .div_green's drag bind.

```
$('.div_red').trigger('drag');
```

but not providing the ui's value,

```
$('.div_green')
.draggable()
.bind('drag',function(event,ui){

    //* $('.div_red').trigger('drag'); // ui is missing, you should provide the ui here
    * $('.div_red').trigger('drag', ui); // passing ui here

    $('.log').html("drag green - left:" + ui.position.left);

});
```

Check statement start with `*`

or you can get the ui of element by `$(this).data('draggable')`
You can change code for .div_red, like

```
$('.div_red')
.draggable()
.bind('drag', function(event,ui){

    if(ui != null)
         $('.log2').html("drag_to_simulate - left:"+ ui.position.left);
    else
        $('.log2').html("drag_to_simulate - left:"+ $(this).data('draggable').position.left);

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
But I already tried that: $('.div_red').trigger('drag',[event,ui]); http://jsfiddle.net/9sNEK/20/
it doesn't work :(

Comment: have updated answer,  replace with $('.div_red').trigger('drag', ui);

Comment: otherwise how can I retrieve the "ui" of a element? something like this: $(this).get('ui')?

Comment: yes! it works thank you very much! 
I try if i can simulate the dragging for the red div! if you have a method thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to reflect red div movement by green div dragging?

Comment: Yes please, Knowing that the red div is draggable too. many thanks Yograj!

Answer (score 0):

I think your order of  tags is wrong!!!

I had the same problem once....

e.g.

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

And then switched them... and boom!! That's was it!! Hope this helps!!!